# Javers async commit into Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, javers

Looking for some proper documentation on async commit for mongo db . We have a spring boot app where we are trying to generate audits for our domain objects , we would like to commit the audits generated by javers into mongo db asynchronously while our main SQL based transaction is fr of this mongodb call.  Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Javers Spring Boot Mongo starter, you can simply put the `@JaversAuditableAsync` ann on a repository method.

There are limitations:
It works only with Mongo and there is no integration for *magical-autogenerated* `ReactiveMongoRepository` yet. So you have to put the `@JaversAuditableAsync` on an actual method which does the save.

```
    @Repository
    interface DummyObjectReactiveRepository 
        extends ReactiveMongoRepository<DummyObject, String> { }

    ...

    @Repository
    class MyRepository {
        @Autowired DummyObjectReactiveRepository dummyObjectReactiveRepository;
    
        @JaversAuditableAsync
        void save(DummyObject d){
            dummyObjectReactiveRepository.save(d)
        }
    }
```